# Get file case-sensitive name, with case-insensitive spelling

Tags: java, string, file, io

I am making an application where the user picks a file from:

`FilePicker.PickFile(filename)`

where `filename` is a string.

In the method, it will translate into:

`File file = new File(filename);`

and nothing is wrong with that. Next, I do,

```
if(file.exists()){
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
else{
    System.out.println("Fail.");
}
```

and this is where the problem begins. I want to get the name of the file, say "HELLO.txt," but if `filename` is "hello.txt," it still passes the `file.exists()` check, and `file.getName()` returns as "hello.txt," not "HELLO.txt". Is there a way, to return `file.getName()` as the case-sensitive version as "HELLO.txt?" Thanks!

**An example:**

`HELLO.txt is the real file`

`FilePicker.PickFile("hello.txt");`

**OUTPUT:**

`hello.txt`

Comment: yes, i am, i like linux, but my GPU doesnt work with the kernel :(

Comment: I don't think there is a solution to that, unfortunately. NTFS is case preserving, not case insensitive...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using Windows, which is case preserving (FAT32/NTFS/..), you can use [`file.getCanonicalFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29)`.getName()` to get the canonical name of the selected file.

When you are using Linux or Android and you want to select a file based on a file name that does not necessarily match case, iterate through all files in the file's directory (`file.getParent()`), and pick the one that `.equalsIgnoreCase` the `filename`. Or see [Case-insensitive File.equals on case-sensitive file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297879/case-insensitive-file-equals-on-case-sensitive-file-system?rq=1)

Comment: I see one problem with this solution - it does not work well with symlinks since getCanonicalFile according to the documentation will resolve symlinks!

Comment: A second problem with this answer is that it doesn't work on Android. So the strikethrough version is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Java 7 and above on Windows, you can use [Path#toRealPath(NOFOLLOW_LINKS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) and it would be more correct than getCanonicalFile() in the presence of symlinks.

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: The API Docs of Path#toRealPath() as linked above say : "it derives from this path, an absolute path that locates the same file as this path, but with name elements that represent the actual name of the directories and the file" .

This is exactly what the original submitter wanted. The option NOFOLLOW_LINKS suppresses resolution of symbolic links ... ie the side-effect of getCanonicalPath() which user11171 critiziced does not occur.

Comment: This works, but toRealPath may return different results for the same file at different times. E.g. directly after renaming a file on disk it may still return the old value. I experienced that on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for help, it seems to be the correct answer

Comment: ~~~
Path pathFileExists = pathfile.toRealPath(LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
~~~

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Maps lower case strings to their case insensitive File
 */
private static final Map<String, File> insensitiveFileHandlerCache = new HashMap<String, File>();

/**
 * Case insensitive file handler. Cannot return <code>null</code>
 */
public static File newFile(String path) {
    if (path == null)
        return new File(path);
    path = path.toLowerCase();
    // First see if it is cached
    if (insensitiveFileHandlerCache.containsKey(path)) {
        return insensitiveFileHandlerCache.get(path);
    } else {
        // If it is not cached, cache it (the path is lower case)
        File file = new File(path);
        insensitiveFileHandlerCache.put(path, file);

        // If the file does not exist, look for the real path
        if (!file.exists()) {

            // get the directory
            String parentPath = file.getParent();
            if (parentPath == null) {
                // No parent directory? -> Just return the file since we can't find the real path
                return file;
            }

            // Find the real path of the parent directory recursively
            File dir = Util.newFile(parentPath);

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (files == null) {
                // If it is not a directory
                insensitiveFileHandlerCache.put(path, file);
                return file;
            }

            // Loop through the directory and put everything you find into the cache
            for (File otherFile : files) {
                // the path of our file will be updated at this point
                insensitiveFileHandlerCache.put(otherFile.getPath().toLowerCase(), otherFile);
            }

            // if you found what was needed, return it
            if (insensitiveFileHandlerCache.containsKey(path)) {
                return insensitiveFileHandlerCache.get(path);
            } 
        }
        // Did not find it? Return the file with the original path
        return file;
    }
}
```

Use

```
File file = newFile(path);
```

instead of

```
File file = new File(path);
```

It's backed by a cache so it shouldn't be too slow. Did a few test runs and it seems to work. It recursively checks the the parent directories to see if they do have the correct letter cases. Then it lists for each directory all files and caches their correct letter casing. In the end it checks if the file with the path has been found and returns the file with the case sensitive path.